# Model to predict coronavirus (covid19) spread

Tags: machine-learning, predictive-modeling, statistics

im new in data sience and machine learning but i have some mathematical and statistics backgroud. I really just want some information about models (like papers or raw models). So if you have any information please share them with me.

thank you

Comment: Information about models in general?

Comment: Yes. Like forecast, etc.

Comment: Timeseries? Supervised learning?... There are a ton of types of model

Comment: Any would be helpful, even simple linear regressions estimations. Thank you Carlos :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a beginner, I would say the SIR model is a great place to start:

https://idmod.org/docs/general/model-sir.html

Numberphile did a great video on using SIR to predict Covid-19:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k6nLfCbAzgo

Hopefully this can get you started on your journey!